# How to access all constant variables of a class

Tags: php, php-5.4

I have a class

```
class iAmConstantClass
{
    const const1 = 'P';
    const const2 = 'T';
}
```

Now i need to validate a variable whose possible values can be any values that exists in class.

So can is there way by which i can loop all variables of a class i.e i can obtain value 'P' and 'T' without knowing variable name `const1` and `const2`.

Comment: Take a look at phps `reflection` feature. http://php.net/language.oop5.reflection

Comment: Constants are the exact opposite of variables, "constant variables" do not exist.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) class for your needs:

```
$refl = new ReflectionClass('iAmConstantClass');
foreach($refl->getConstants() as $const){
  echo $const; // output will be PT
}
```